# Check if varlist contains factor variables?

Tags: stata

I am trying to check if the *varlist* in my program contains factor variables. I follow the recommendation by StataCorp in this page (http://www.stata.com/support/faqs/programming/factor-variable-support/). The suggested codes are:

```
syntax varlist(fv)
local fvops = "`s(fvops)'" == "true" | _caller() >= 11
if `fvops' {
    // within this loop, you can expand the factor variable list,
    // create a local for version control and perform any other
    // steps needed for factor operated varlists
}
```

Nevertheless, it now appears to me that the macro `s(fvops)` does not really check the existence of factor variables in the *varlist*. A simple example to illustrate:

```
capture program drop test_fvops
program test_fvops
syntax varlist(fv)
local fvops = "`s(fvops)'" == "true" | _caller() >= 11
qui reg `varlist'
if `fvops'  {
    di "factor variables specified"
}
else {
    di "factor variables not specified"
}
end

sysuse auto,clear
test_fvops price mpg foreign weight i.rep78
test_fvops price mpg foreign weight rep78
```

Oddly, the last two lines of the code both return "factor variables specified". The program could not tell the second line has no factor variables.

A further probe on the properties of the macro `s(fvops)` only makes me more confused.

```
sysuse auto,clear
qui reg price mpg foreign weight i.rep78
local fvops = "`s(fvops)'" != "true" | _caller() >= 11
di "|s(fvops)=`s(fvops)'|fvops=`fvops'|"

qui reg price mpg foreign weight rep78
local fvops = "`s(fvops)'" != "true" | _caller() >= 11
di "|s(fvops)=`s(fvops)'|fvops=`fvops'|"
```

In both cases, `s(fvops)` is empty but `fvops` is 1. I also tried to `return list` and `sreturn list` and did not see `s(fvops)`.

Am I using the `fvops` code correctly? I am running this with Stata 13 on Win 7.

Added:
Nick's comment clarifies something I couldn't find in the manual. So basically the `_caller()` segment shouldn't have been included, and this quote from the linked page was what I needed to understand about `s(fvops)`.

> "To check if factor variables were specified in the varlist, you may use the saved macro `s(fvops)` from syntax, which will be equal to “true” when factor variables are specified >and empty otherwise."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With your own program: You are working with Stata 13 and your program does not set `version` to anything else.

Hence `_caller()` is greater than 11 in both cases and your test is no test.

Why not just try displaying the value of `s(fvops)`?

With the later code, your "further probe": Why expect `s(fvops)` to be visible? You never created it, as you did not use `syntax`. But the local macro `fvops` is 1 for the same reason: `_caller()` is more than 11 and the `|` operator selects 1.

Comment: Great! Thank you for pointing out the version issue--I should've noticed that. I also wasn't sure s(fvops) was the product of `syntax`, so that really helps clarify how the macro works.